# Iframe script not loading in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, iframe, shopify

When I logged in from shopify admin at that time it works but in Incognito mode Its not working.I am using Iframe in shopify theme app extension

In Mozila and Safari browser its working.In chrome Settings > Privacy and security > Cookies and other site data > Allow all cookies If I did settings then it works.But how users will do these settings.So I need to add code for this

I am getting below error
DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document

Comment: You can't modify the settings on the user side, simply made a check or local storage, if fail then simply show a banner that suggests custom to take regarded actions.